# g++ error: no matching function for call to ‘fpclassify(float&)’

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I use GCC 5.4.0 and Boost 1.67.0 on a Fedora 26 system (this is not the system's default compiler). If I compile the following `a.cpp`:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
```

with the command-line:

```
g++ a.cpp -c -o a.o  --std=c++11 -D__CORRECT_ISO_CPP11_MATH_H_PROTO -I/path/to/boost/include
```

I get the following error:

```
... blah blah blah ...
/path/to/boost/include/boost/container_hash/detail/hash_float.hpp:212:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘fpclassify(float&)’
         switch (std::fpclassify(v))
... blah blah blah ...
```

If I don't define `_CORRECT_ISO_CPP11_MATH_H_PROTO` compilation concludes with no errors.

This didn't use to happen to me with previous Boost versions. e.g. 1.62.0. Why is it happening now?

Note: It appears this happens with some GCC 6.x versions: [GCC 6.1](https://godbolt.org/g/cSv4nz) (Godbolt) and 6.2, but not with 6.3 and later versions. Thanks @Justin. Also, this doesn't happen with clang v3.5 and later (not extensively tested).

Comment: What version of boost where you using before you upgraded?

Comment: Could be gcc thing. Do you have access to newer compiler? Also, you are compiling it with C++11, I assume? Also, CUDA has nothing to do with that, I will edit the tags. Also, you just created an `fpclassify` tag. Why?

Comment: @NathanOliver: See edit.

Comment: @SergeyA: See edit.

Comment: Reproduced with GCC 6.1 (couldn't with 5.4.0): https://godbolt.org/g/cSv4nz

Comment: @SergeyA: About an fplcassify tag - this question is related to the fpclassify function in the standard C++ library, so I typed fpclassify. I was assuming maybe there's a similar tag with actual questions about fpclassify (maybe with a slightly different name) and someone might correct me.

Comment: @einpoklum There is no need to create a tag for a *specific* function. Do you realize how many functions are in the standard library? In the boost library? WAY too many to tag individually.  Tagging a library is enough, and there are already existing tags for that

Comment: @RemyLebeau: 1. There are lots of standard-library-function-specific tags on SO. 2. It's possible that a tag for fpclassify is too much. So - at some point someone will just delete the tag.

Comment: @M.M: `_CORRECT_ISO_CPP11_MATH_H_PROTO`, see edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be reproduced by:

```
#define __CORRECT_ISO_CPP11_MATH_H_PROTO 1
#include <cmath>

int main()
{ 
    float v;
    std::fpclassify(v);
}
```

The C++11 standard (N3337) specifies the 3 overloads for `std::fpclassify` for the 3 floating point types (without `constexpr`).

The code fails to compile because the `cmath` header [in these versions of gcc](https://code.woboq.org/boost/include/c++/5.3.0/cmath.html) contains (pseudocode):

```
#include <math.h>
#undef fpclassify

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#ifndef __CORRECT_ISO_CPP11_MATH_H_PROTO
constexpr int fpclassify(float __x) {.....}    
constexpr int fpclassify(double __x) {.....}    
constexpr int fpclassify(long double __x) {.....}
#endif

template<typename _Tp>
constexpr typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<__is_integer<_Tp>::__value, int>::__type
fpclassify(_Tp __x)
{
```

Which means that  `std::fpclassify` is only found by an integer argument.  (I believe this integer overload is to satisfy the general math requirement that integer arguments to floating point functions should invoke the `double` overload).

---

I found [the relevant commit to libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/f8b67ee90fda9ae687d8f154ed09ce0b585f27d6).  The commentary suggests that this macro should only be defined if `math.h` already provided the three overloads of `fpclassify` for the three floating point types.

The autoconf code for libstdc++ checks the existing system `math.h` and emits this macro if it already defined the three overloads of `fpclassify`.

If you are on an implementation where `math.h` does not provide the overloads then you should not use this macro, otherwise you render your implementation non-conforming.

Answer (score 3):

Defining `__CORRECT_ISO_CPP11_MATH_H_PROTO` means "the libc that this libstdc++ was configured and built against has a `math.h` that provides the C++11 functions, so `<cmath>` shouldn't try to provide its own".

Why on earth are you defining that macro yourself?

Comment: This used to be suggested for some scenarios involving CUDA.